# "import lib.subpackage.blah as foo" issue - "AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'subpackage'"

Tags: python, python-import

My filesystem structure:

- `main.py`.
- `lib/`

  - `__init__.py`.
  - `subpackage/`

    - `__init__.py`.
    - `app.py`
    - `sched.py`

**main.py**:

```
import lib.subpackage
```

**lib/__init__.py** is empty.

**lib/subpackage/__init__.py**:

```
import lib.subpackage.sched
import lib.subpackage.app
```

**lib/subpackage/app.py**:

```
import lib.subpackage.sched as foo
```

**lib/subpackage/sched.py** is empty.

---

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\logix\Desktop\code_\from_linux\dbg\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.subpackage
  File "c:\Users\logix\Desktop\code_\from_linux\dbg\lib\subpackage\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import lib.subpackage.app
  File "c:\Users\logix\Desktop\code_\from_linux\dbg\lib\subpackage\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.subpackage.sched as foo
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'subpackage'
```

I'm using Python 3.6.4 from the command line.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I was getting there, testing out my hypothesis.

Comment: Actually, this is a known bug; writing up the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the import machinery, when using an alias; reported as [issue #23203](https://bugs.python.org/issue23203):

> Aliasing import of sub-{module,package} from the package raises AttributeError on import.
>
> We have three nested packages: `foo` -> `bar` -> `baz`. The `bar` package imports `foo.bar.baz`. We try to `import foo.bar`. This works well unless we try to alias the `foo.bar.baz` import in `foo.bar` with the `import ... as ...` syntax.

The bugfix for this is part of Python 3.7 (currently in alpha release only).

The work-around is to use a relative import:

```
from . import sched as foo
```